# How to develop code with multiple tasks in parallel?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing, iot

I need to develop a Firmware to my IoT device based in Python3 in a RPi Model 3B+. The project needs handle a led matrix where is show messages received by an API, needs play voice messages, serve requests and states of GPIO, sends MQTT Alerts, etc. and I need run the program steadily.

My dubts are in how to develop all my class/functions to deploy my code effectively in the RaspberryPi. Do I've to use Thread or Multiprocess ?

I have read  about these themes and i know some things, like the threads run in the same memory space, while processes have separate memory, also i have read that If the code has a lot of I/O or Network I should use Threads or If the code is CPU I should use multiprocessing.

However, I would like have some opinions about my case. 
Some commments?
Thanks

Comment: Hard to say without more details but it all sounds like low bandwidth stuff and fairly unrelated to each other so there is no great penalty for passing messages between processes and if you use processes you get to use all 4 CPU cores without the GIL, so I'd be inclined to go for multi-processing. My guess is that either would work. Go ahead and run some tests.

Comment: Yes, really the bandwidth use is low, I also thought about using multiprocessing however I wanted listen some opinions. Thanks Dude